# Analog gauges in BGE

Tags: game-engine

How would I make analog gauges (like fuel, RPM, etc.) in the BGE?
I have tried using orientation constraints but it did not work.

Comment: Could you include an example of what you've done so far?  You can upload your file to Blend Exchange for free.  https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/sites-to-use-for-uploading-images-and-files

Comment: I got rid of the file but all I had was a circle and needle. The needle had 2 torque logic bricks, (one being invert) and 2 orientation constraints. The idea was when it reached a certain angle it would stop rotating.

Comment: You do not need python for this. Consider, for example, a fuel gauge. You can make a simple animation of the gauge's needle with frame 1 of the needle being on empty and frame 100 being on full. Then have an integer property on the needle. Using an action actuator set to property, you can gave the value of that property control the frame of the animation - so if you are on frame 50, it would show the fuel tank as half full. Now on your vehicle, or wherever you keep track of fuel, you can just use the property actuator there to copy the real fuel property's value to your gauge.

Answer (score 0):

well you could use like a python script.
set the origin point of the needle to its bottom and.

why not something like this tied to an always actuator?

```
    import bge
    from bge import logic
    from math import degrees

    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner
    own_rotation = own.worldOrientation.to_euler()
    POINT=own["AMOUNT"]
    MAXPOINT=1
    MINPOINT=0
    if ( POINT < MAXPOINT) & ( POINT > MINPOINT):
        own.worldOrientation = (0,0,POINT)
    elif POINT > MAXPOINT:
        own.worldOrientation = (0,0,MAXPOINT)
    elif POINT < MINPOINT:
        own.worldOrientation = (0,0,MINPOINT)
```

it should set the rotation every time a value changes. you can change the Amount property every time you want the meter to go up or down, and the meter will follow it. 
NOTE: this takes in RADIANS not DEGREES! and Sets it in RADIANS!